# Black Screen after booting Kali Linux after installation

Tags: grub, kali-linux, black-screen-of-death

So here I'm after I was so excited to try the new Kali Linux operating system. I've tried to install it with a dual boot with Windows 10 with creating a new partition for the new system. And I guess I did it perfectly. Everything seems fine according to other Kali Linux installations. I've downloaded the 64bit 2016 2.0 (the latest version).

When I launched my PC the GRUB menu appeared and I've selected Kali GNU/Linux to run the system. I get a short list of command that starts to appear, the last line is something that say something like this:

```
dev8/ ... clean ..........30210/200125.... blocks
```

<sub>I'm sorry I don't remember the line correctly, this is just so you can understand. I'm writing this on Windows.</sub>

The thing is that after this line it's like it was on a low resolution then suddenly become in hd or the resolution changed. After a couple of seconds everything goes black, no cursor on the screen, no where to type anything, no login, just nothing!

I think it's a graphic card problem maybe, I have a Intel Graphic HD card.
I can't run any terminal or nothing, please if you have a fix for this just help because I really need this system for my studies.

Here's the conf of my PC:

- Dell Laptop Inspiron 15
- 4go of ram ddr3
- Intel HD Graphic card
- Intel Celeron N3050 x-64 based processor 1.6Ghz

Could you give me a step by step fix because I'm very new at Kali Linux and I'm very excited to learn about it.
And please don't tell me to install it on a VMware because I tried and it was very slow. I would prefer a Hard Drive Installation.

Comment: I'm also looking for a permanent solution to this. Meanwhile, try logging in while the monitor is on standby. Just type in: root [enter] toor [enter]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try presssing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a terminal.
2. Login using the credentials you input during installation.
3. Type `ps -ef | grep X` to verify that the Xserver is running.

Comment: well that's the problem Ctrl + Alt +F1 is not working.  I've tried Ctrl + Alt + F1-F6 nothing work. I've tried to add nomodeset in the grub command. Kali booted until the login screen. I've entered my username and my password but after entering my password the screen freez on the page and i'm not able to do anything. i've tried to press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to login with command but seems that this keys not working (my keyboard work perfectly). if you could help me that would be very great. i really need it.

Answer (score 0):

@hakim, I faced similar type of issue before also I posted my question on this forum if you are interested you can take a look.

Now coming back to your question, yes its the display issue which affected Kali to load the login screen.

There will be two solutions or workaround I can suggest you. check with the display drivers for your computer and try to install using the terminal if you're able to access Fail safe mode (this should list when GRUB screen shows-up)

If that doesn't work then I would say you have to reinstall it again. Let me know if you need help in finding the drivers for your display model. I'm glad to help.

Comment: How would reinstalling help if they do it the same way? What should they do differently to get a better result?